# VueJS mouseover in for loop

Tags: for-loop, vue.js, mouseover

I have a for that will create a component for each index.

In this component, I have a child div containing edit, add, minus buttons.
I would like it to be displayed on the component mouseover.

How do I achieve this dynamically without having to play with indexes ?

Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Post` component

```
<template>
  <div v-on:mouseleave.native="showOperations = false"
       v-on:mouseover.native="showOperations = true">
    <!-- post data -->
    <div v-if="showOperations">
      <!-- operations -->
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  ...
  data () {
    return {
      showOperations: false
    }
  },
  ...
</script>
```

List of post

```
<post v-for="post in posts"
      :key="post.id"
      :post="post">
</post>
```

This pattern works for me and I think it works for you as well

Comment: Thank you ! If I understand right, showOperations will only belong to the actual post and not be a shared variable ! It works on my side, thank you ! I feel stupid, I got so used to Vuex that I forgot the basics. I used \@mouseover and \@mouseout fyi.