# Vuetify on mouseover toggle data object within array list

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, mouseover

I am trying to implement a functionality which will toggle a Vuetify badge element for each array object within the list when the containing div has been hovered over.

I am able to create a hover like functionality within v-for array list using css, which is fairly simple but how can I achieve similar outcome using vuetify components? As I have not found any questions discussing this or demonstrating it, assume it is possible. Have looked into

1. [First Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54224919/vuetify-list-menu-activator-visibility-toggle)
2. [Second Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52808658/vuejs-mouseover-in-for-loop)
3. [Second Link](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/loading-icon-in-loop/13183/3)

And much more but have not found similar enough example of what I desire.

I have added codepen example of what I currently have.
The badge should only appear on the element which is currently being hovered, however all badge elements are being executed when any element has been hovered on.

**[CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/GucciRoman/pen/aboLjwd?editors=1010#anon-signup)**

Maybe I have missed out something obvious

**HTML Part**

```
  <template>
   <div id="app">
      <div>My favourite fruit is <b>{{favouriteFruit}}</b></div> <br>

   <div v-for="(dataArray, index) in testArray" @click="setCurrent(dataArray.name)">
      <v-badge
              :color="computedFavFruitColor[index]"
              right
              v-model="show"
      >
         <template v-slot:badge>
            <span><v-icon color="#ECF0FF">{{computedFavFruit[index]}}</v-icon></span>
         </template>
        <div @mouseover="show = true" @mouseleave="show = false">
           {{dataArray.name}}
        </div>
      </v-badge>

   </div>
   </div>
</template>
```

Any further help of suggestions regarding this manner would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the show property is global, it counts for every item you hover. You want to target the element you hover. So I suggest to keep track of the index of the item you hover like this: https://codepen.io/reijnemans/pen/JjPrayp?editors=1010

```
    <div v-for="(dataArray, index) in testArray" @click="setCurrent(dataArray.name)">
      <v-badge
              :color="computedFavFruitColor[index]"
              right
      >
         <template v-slot:badge>
            <span v-if="show == index"><v-icon color="#ECF0FF">{{computedFavFruit[index]}}</v-icon></span>
         </template>
        <div @mouseenter="show = index" @mouseleave="show = null">
           {{dataArray.name}}
        </div>
      </v-badge>

   </div>
```

And `show = null` ipv `show = true` in data block of vue